# How to use nested loops in finding duplicates is List

Tags: java

I'm trying to create program to show dupicate numbers which duplicate specified times in the list.
numberOfDuplicates int value says the requiment ex. '2' -> should print only 2, '3' -> 4,3.
Thinking about creating "counter" list and putting "if" but can't put it all together.

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(4,2,3,4,5,3,4,2,3);
        int numberOfDuplicates;
        for (int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < integers.size(); j++) {
                if (integers.get(i).equals(integers.get(j))) {
                    // got the duplicate element
                    System.out.println(integers.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class CountOccurrences {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a mutable (modifiable) list of integers from
    // given values.
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3));

    // Create a map storing the value and the number of
    // occurrences in the list.
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();

    // While we still have elements in the original list
    // of integers, add an entry into the map.
    while (integers.size() != 0) {
      // Add the value and number of occurrences.
      // The number of occurrences is obtained using
      // Collections.frequency().
      occurrences.put(integers.get(0), Collections.frequency(integers, integers.get(0)));

      // Remove all occurrences (to avoid duplicate counting)
      removeAllOccurrences(integers.get(0), integers);
    }
    // Print map
    System.out.println(occurrences);
  }

  public static void removeAllOccurrences(Integer integer, List<Integer> list) {
    while (list.contains(integer)) {
      list.remove(integer);
    }
  }
}
```

Some things to mention:

- `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3))` creates a mutable version of the `List` so that the `remove()` function is supported.
- The `HashMap` stores a key-value pair with the key being the item value and value being the number of occurrences.
- Here is the output of the program:

```
{2=2, 3=3, 4=3, 5=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method add of Set returns a boolean whether a value already exists (true if it does not exist, false if it already exists, see Set [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) ).

So just iterate through all the values:

```
public Set<Integer> findDuplicates(List<Integer> listContainingDuplicates) { 
  final Set<Integer> setToReturn = new HashSet<>(); 
  final Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
  for (Integer yourInt : listContainingDuplicates){
     if (!set1.add(yourInt))
       setToReturn.add(yourInt);
  return setToReturn;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3);

    Map<Integer, Integer> intTimes = new HashMap<>();
    for (Integer i : integers)
        intTimes.merge(i, 1, (a, b) -> a + b);
    System.out.println("intTimes = " + intTimes);

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> timesInts = new TreeMap<>();
    for (Entry<Integer, Integer> e : intTimes.entrySet())
        if (e.getValue() > 1)
            timesInts.computeIfAbsent(e.getValue(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
                .add(e.getKey());
    System.out.println("timesInts = " + timesInts);

    for (Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> e : timesInts.entrySet())
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> "
            + e.getValue().stream()
                .map(i -> i.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}
```

output:

```
intTimes = {2=2, 3=3, 4=3, 5=1}
timesInts = {2=[2], 3=[3, 4]}
2 -> 2
3 -> 3, 4
```